# Own class object attribute get overridden

Tags: c#

I have created an object with the attributes String, and the other is a `List<String>`.
I have also created a `static List<MyObject>` where i add then all my Objects.
Now my Problem is the second attribute is getting overridden.

For example I have 3 Objects:

```
Object1: "Name"; List with 3 Strings
Object2: "Name2"; List with 2 Strings
Object3: "Name3"; List with 5 Strings
```

If i add them now to my Object List, it looks like so

```
Name; List with 5 Strings
Name2; List with 5 Strings
Name3; List with 5 Strings
```

It override the second attributes to all the other Objects in the List.

**Code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (elo.ReadObjMask(i) > 0)
    {
        var iRet = elo.PrepareObjectEx(0, 0, i); 
        maskenname = elo.ObjMName(); 
        if (maskenname != "")
        {
            for (int e = 0; e < 50; e++)
            {
                string eigenschaft = elo.GetObjAttribName(e); 

                if (eigenschaft != "" && eigenschaft != "-")
                {
                    eigenschaften.Add(eigenschaft); 
                }
            }
            allMasks.Add(maskenname); 

        }
        else 
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
        EloMask emask = new EloMask(maskenname, eigenschaften); 
        staticVariables.allMask.Add(emask); 
        eigenschaften.Clear(); 
    }
}
```

Here is my object class:

```
public class EloMask
{
    public string name;
    public List<String> eigenschaften;

    public EloMask(string iname, List<String> ieigenschaften)
    {
        name = iname;
        eigenschaften = ieigenschaften;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the code for your "Object" class and how you are instantiating and adding to the static list.

Comment: staticVariables.allMask.Add(emask); in this part i add it to my static List

Comment: I believe that:
EloMask emask = new EloMask(maskenname, eigenschaften);
is passing eigenschaften as a reference, so when it gets changed so will all the others.
You need to initiate a new instance of your list before writing to it.

    eigenschaften = new List<string>;

Comment: try changing this line eigenschaften.Clear(); to eigenschaften = new List<string>();

Comment: OMG so easy! Thank you, this solved my problem!

Comment: Btw, you should start to use english names for everything. Especially if you seek help, you want people having an easy time to understand what the variables are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List<string>` always points to the same instance because you are passing a reference to the list, not a copy. As a result, the list is cleared and filled again for each `EloMask` that you pass that list into.

To fix your issue, create a new list instead:

```
if (elo.ReadObjMask(i) > 0)
{
    var iRet = elo.PrepareObjectEx(0, 0, i);
    maskenname = elo.ObjMName();

    // create a new list here!!!
    var eigenschaften = new List<string>();

    if (maskenname != "")
    {
        for (int e = 0; e < 50; e++)
        {
            string eigenschaft = elo.GetObjAttribName(e);

            if (eigenschaft != "" && eigenschaft != "-")
            {
                eigenschaften.Add(eigenschaft);
            }
        }

        allMasks.Add(maskenname);

    }

    EloMask emask = new EloMask(maskenname, eigenschaften);
    staticVariables.allMask.Add(emask);

    // clearing the list is no longer needed                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can do what you want:

```
    public static List<Person> PersonsList = new List<Person>();
    public static Random rd = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            List<string> tmpAbilities = new List<string>() {((char)rd.Next(255)).ToString(), ((char)rd.Next(255)).ToString() , ((char)rd.Next(255)).ToString() };
            Person tmpPerson = new Person("TmpName_"+i,tmpAbilities);
            PersonsList.Add(tmpPerson);
        }
        foreach (var persona in PersonsList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(persona);
        }
    }


    public class Person
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<string> Abilities;

        public Person(string name,List<string> abilities)
        {
            Name = name;
            Abilities = abilities;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string retVal = $"Name: {Name}\n";
            foreach (var ability in Abilities)
            {
                retVal += $"Ability : {ability}\n";
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {

            if (elo.ReadObjMask(i) > 0)
            {
                // Create a new listin here
                eigenschaften = new List<string>();

                var iRet = elo.PrepareObjectEx(0, 0, i);
                maskenname = elo.ObjMName();
                if (maskenname != "")
                {
                    for (int e = 0; e < 50; e++)
                    {
                        string eigenschaft = elo.GetObjAttribName(e);

                        if (eigenschaft != "" && eigenschaft != "-")
                        {
                            eigenschaften.Add(eigenschaft);
                        }
                    }
                    allMasks.Add(maskenname);

                }

                else
                {
                    // Do nothing
                }
                EloMask emask = new EloMask(maskenname, eigenschaften);
                staticVariables.allMask.Add(emask);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Troy! You are missing () here: eigenschaften = new List<string>;

Comment: No Problem, i thank you much again! I struggled at it yesterday 3 hours haha:D